# SVN List Revision Numbers Command

Tags: linux, svn, terminal

I'm looking for a command that will list all of the SVN revisions at a particular URL, and nothing more. I'm working on an Ubuntu machine. Simply, for example, I would like the output of the command to be:

```
r43
r42
r41
....list every revision
```

or just

```
43
42
41
....list every revision
```

Is this possible? Because I'm using it remotely, I can't use the

```
svnlook history
```

command. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
svn log <URL> | egrep '^r[0-9]' | sed -e 's/^r\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/'
```

I works for me on an ubuntu machine from a bash shell.